# Use CORS to prevent others from embedding my video

Tags: javascript, html, cors, video-streaming

I have a site with an HLS video content on it. For example, when a user visits my site in Safari, I play the video like so:

```
<video controls>
    <source src=“playlist.m3u8” type =“application/x-mpegURL”>
</video>
```

This .m3u8 playlist points to *.ts video fragments on my server.

Can I **prevent other people from embedding this video on their website**? More specifically, prevent the players in browsers to download the *.ts fragments from my server.

I feel like **CORS** might be the solution here, but I am not sure how to implement this or if it’s even possible.

**I don’t care about someone stealing my content and hosting it on their own server.** I just want to make it harder for them to play it straight from my server to stop unnecessary server load.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://your.site`

Comment: No, CORS only prevents accessing it using JavaScript, it has nothing to do with embedding.

Comment: @Barmar so I could prevent them from playing my video using players like HLS.js, since that’s probably using Javascript to fetch the content?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @s_joe77 I don't know how that works. If it creates a DOM element that references the playlist, it will still work.